# How to move a Gtk::Window with native widows api?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gtk, gtkmm

### Background

I am developing an application in C++ with Gtkmm 4. I am creating a Gtk::Window. Now i want to move this window to the center of the screen. In Gtkmm 3 there were methods such as `Gtk::Window::set_position` and `Gtk::Window::move`, but they were removed in Gtkmm 4. I have already worked out how to get the screen size from `Gdk::Display`, and calculate the position.
But, i have to use platform specific API to move my window. On Linux, there is X11 and Wayland, and i know how to do it with these.

### Question

How can i move a `Gtk::Window` to a specific position on screen with native windows API ?

Comment: There is a good reason not to move windows programmatically, which might be the reason `set_position` and `move` were removed. Did you think of users with multiple screens? What about tiled window managers? If you're really sure you want to write broken code, you can use the `SetWindowPos` function of WinAPI.

Comment: @YakovGalka SetWindowPos takes a window handle (HWND) as first argument. How can i convert a Gtk::Window to a windows window handle ?

Comment: @frederic Does [this](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/getting-a-win32-window-handle-from-a-gtkwindow/2480) help?

Comment: @BobMorane yes, thanks, that was just what i searched for ! If you make an answer with it, i will accept it.

Comment: Glad I could help. I would leave the anwer to you if you don't mind. I don't have a Windows copy here so I can't test anything.

Comment: @BobMorane ok, i could'nt test it either, i do not have windows either ! (Maybe someone else could test it please ?)

Comment: @BobMorane i need your help one more time : i am on linux, installed gtk and dependencies with jhbuild, and i simply CANNOT find <gdk/gdkwin32.h> :( in the installation prefix

Comment: @BobMorane i found out myself already : As i am on Linux, this header had been downloaded but OF COURSE not installed ! And please make an answer with your research so that i can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this source](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/getting-a-win32-window-handle-from-a-gtkwindow/2480):

> GDK exports `gdk_win32_window_get_handle()` as a public symbol—but its
> declaration is not available in a public header, so you’ll have to
> define it yourself:
>
> `HGDIOBJ       gdk_win32_window_get_handle (GdkWindow *window);`

It seems a `<gdk/gdkwin32.h>` header is also available, which makes the macro `GDK_WINDOW_HWND` available to simplify things a bit. An example is provided [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/video/gstvideooverlay.html?gi-language=c#gstvideooverlay-and-gtk).

Answer (score 0):

The method of getting the HWND has changed.
The information can be read [here](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/can-i-still-use-gdk-window-hwnd-macro-in-gtkmm4/5406).

Personally, the following script worked well for me in the window creation function (using gtkmm4):

```
//Create GTK window
auto win = new Window();
add_window(*win);
win->show();

//Take HWND
auto surface = win->get_surface()->gobj();
auto hWnd= (HWND)GDK_SURFACE_HWND(surface);
```